# How do you create an RSS URL that can be used on someone elses website from sharepoint 2010

Tags: rss

I enabled the site setting to allow RSS, I enabled the Document Library setting to allow RSS and point directly to the document. I added a content query web part to my page and created the RSS Feed with the Icon with link to a page that allows you to Subscribe to the RSS feed from our site.

I would like to provide a visitor a link that they can take and put on their own website.

Where do I find this URL.  I have tried the URL of the RSS Icon Link and I have also tried the URL of the "Subscribe to this RSS Feed" link.

Thanks you

Answer (score 1):

RSS Feeds are enabled on each list/library in SharePoint 2010, with the exception of Pages Library (and some others, not very common for usage) - but NOT by default enabled. In order to benefit from it, basically after enabling at the level of the Web Application, then Site Collection (under "Allow RSS for this site collection") followed by enabling it at the level of the List/Library where needed (usually is targeting the Application page listFeed.aspx under _layouts, followed by the Identifier of the List, the GUID)

Once this is done you get the Url by simply using the RSS button in the Ribbon.

Other ways involve using the CQWP, but is not needed for the above to work properly, but rather for scenarios such as the Pages Libraries, or Cross sites selections, etc. / the RSS in a CQWP is handled per each web part by enabling it in the WP settings.

In both cases these are also "authenticated feeds" so make sure the RSS Client knows how to handle that before!

Hope it helps,
C:\Marius

Comment: Hmmm... I tried to get rssowl to read my rss feed, but it couldn't get past the login.

Comment: You would also need to check authentication schemes supported by each Client as the might only work with Basic Authentication instead Windows

Answer (score 0):

The easy solution is to just click the RSS Icon and take the URL from the address bar (remove &Source=...), so you get something like:

> http://www.mycompanysp.com/subsite/_layouts/listfeed.aspx?List=%7BBD3A131A%2D9970%2D4472%2DA7FB%2DC51F28F0015A%7D